# celery: global name 'collections' is not defined

Tags: python, collections, flask, redis, celery

i have a flask app with celery and reds as a broker, configured as follows :

```
import flask
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
app.jinja_env.cache = None

from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
app.config.update(CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://:{}@127.0.0.1:6379/15'.format(os.environ['REDIS_PASSWD']), CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://:{}@127.0.0.1:6379/15'.format(os.environ['REDIS_PASSWD']), CELERY_IMPORTS=("aortabot"), CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300, CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL="DEBUG")
celery = make_celery(app)
```

And here are the contents of redis db 15 :

```
127.0.0.1:6379[15]> keys *
1) "_kombu.binding.celery"
2) "celery-task-meta-307b7f60-33b5-4927-b1a7-d5d47061bb4c"
3) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
4) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
5) "celery-task-meta-e57cef5c-4ac2-4565-b350-5fb0fc109d13"
```

But about the tasks (entries 2 and 5), the Celery log says :

```
[2015-06-28 21:54:45,046: DEBUG/Worker-4] global name 'collections' is not defined
[2015-06-28 21:54:45,048: INFO/MainProcess] Task implement_aortabot[e57cef5c-4ac2-4565-b350-5fb0fc109d13] succeeded in 1.018413604s: None
```

**global name 'collections' is not defined**

in my app, there is only 1 @celery.task defined, and even if i replace the body of the celery.task with "pass", am still getting the same log message .

could you please help me on what might be wrong ?

EDIT: there is 1 file. "collections" is mentioned below :

```
$ cat aortabot.py | egrep collections
import collections
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            netpart[route_instance] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                    info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            netpart[route_instance] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                    info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                info['bgp-rib'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                    info['bgp-rib'][name] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info['cos'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info['ethernet-mac-statistics'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            tip = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            tip = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            'pfe-statistics']['pfe-local-traffic-statistics'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            'pfe-statistics']['pfe-hardware-discard-statistics'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            'pfe-statistics']['pfe-chip-statistics'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        netpart['krt-queue'] = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
            info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netpart = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    netstat = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                    leveled = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(leveled.items()))
                        leveled = collections.OrderedDict(
                registrar = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

NOTE: the code was working previously, after experimenting with redis db 0, and then changed it to db 15, the issue manifested itself

EDIT: this is the only Celery task defined, as mentioned it is not about the task, as if i replace the function body with pass i still encounter the issue

```
@celery.task(name="implement_aortabot", bind=True)
def implement_aortabot(self, diff_):
    with app.test_request_context():
        try:
            uuid_i = uuid.uuid4().hex
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
            diff_['netelement']['pyez'] = Device(host=diff_['netelement']['ip'], user=net_['app']['user'], passwd=net_['app']['passwd'], port=22, gather_facts=False)
            diff_['netelement']['pyez'].open()
            jsnap_like.formulate_netconf_data(diff_['netelement']['pyez'], uuid_i, diff_['netelement']['host'])
            diff_['netelement']['pyez'].close()
            lookup = {
                'maintenance': diff_['control']['maintenance'],
                'username': diff_['username'],
                'timestamp': timestamp,
                'message': diff_['netelement']['host'] + " * " + diff_['control']['maintenance'] + " * " + diff_['username'] + " * " + timestamp,
            }
            if not os.path.exists(net_['registry'] + diff_['netelement']['host'] + ".cfg"):
                registrar = collections.defaultdict(dict)
                registrar['aortabot'][diff_['netelement']['host']] = {}
                registrar['aortabot'][diff_['netelement']['host']][uuid_i] = lookup
                write_file(net_['registry'] + diff_['netelement']['host'] + ".cfg", json.dumps(registrar))
            else:
                registrar = read_file(net_['registry'] + diff_['netelement']['host'] + ".cfg")
                registrar = json.loads(registrar)
                registrar['aortabot'][diff_['netelement']['host']][uuid_i] = lookup
                write_file(net_['registry'] + diff_['netelement']['host'] + ".cfg", json.dumps(registrar))
            action = {
                'status': True,
                'netelement': diff_['netelement']['host'],
                'ip': diff_['netelement']['ip'],
                'maintenance': diff_['control']['maintenance'],
                'timestamp': timestamp,
                'username': diff_['username'],
                'admin_status': False,
                'admin_timestamp': None,
                'admin_username': None,
                #'id': list(irepo.iter_commits())[0].hexsha,
                'id': uuid_i,
            }
            if not search_pickle_object("tasks.json", action):
                insert_pickle_object("tasks.json", action)
            insert_pickle_object("activities.json", action)
        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are referencing a "collections" variable. The code you provided us doesn't appear relevant because it doesn't show the attempted use of this undefined variable.

Comment: Check for any files you might have with the same names as built-in modules. If you find any, rename them. It doesn't look like that's the problem - that tends to manifest with somewhat different error messages - but it's worth looking into.

Comment: @user2357112 no there is no another import of collections. the grep output is after i put all of the functions in aortabot.py which is the one and only .py file

Comment: this is odd because the log level of is `DEBUG` for that statement - normally you would expect `ERROR` - are you sure that some of your tasks are actually failing?

Comment: @scytale, thank you. yes am sure, that it is the the celery task that is failing. am not sure what was wrong. i re-structured the whole app. and no issue anymore.